# double ~ in R interactive terminal in VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use R in VSCode. I downloaded the R extension and followed the steps specified but I keep getting an annoying issue: when I use Alt+126 to write the character '~' in the script everything is fine, but when I run the line, in the R interactive terminal it appears twice. Also, if I use Alt+126 in the R interactive terminal, '~~' appears instead of '~' (two times the character instead of once). I have no idea why this is happening, I tried to uninstall and reinstall both VSCode and R and reset the pc but nothing changed.
I hope somebody knows how to solve this, thanks in advance!

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/145#issuecomment-1139374522 https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17679

Comment: yeah, seems like this was fixed in R >4.0